# Can't start war application on tomcat running on Linux server

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-security

I can't start application on tomcat 7. I've deployed it on tomcat and it doesn't work (on Linux server) but I can run it from eclipse on Windows. Here is the error:

```
Jul 12, 2015 2:48:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:672)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1862)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at cz.prosvaly.configuration.AppInitializer.onStartup(AppInitializer.java:39)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5479)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more

Jul 12, 2015 2:48:16 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
SEVERE: Error deploying configuration descriptor /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:904)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:672)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1862)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here is the AppInitializer

```
    package cz.prosvaly.configuration;

import javax.servlet.FilterRegistration;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter;
import org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(AppConfig.class);
        ctx.setServletContext(container);

        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = container.addServlet(
                "dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));

        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/");

        FilterRegistration.Dynamic fr = container.addFilter("encodingFilter",
                new CharacterEncodingFilter());
        fr.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
        fr.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
        fr.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");

        FilterRegistration.Dynamic filter = container.addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain",
                new DelegatingFilterProxy());
        filter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");


    }

}
```

The error is on this row:

```
filter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");
```

My pom

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>cz.prosvaly</groupId>
    <artifactId>prosvaly</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>Prosvaly.cz</name>

    <properties>
        <springframework.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <org.springframework.security.version>4.0.1.RELEASE</org.springframework.security.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.6.Final</hibernate.version>
        <mysql.version>5.1.31</mysql.version>
        <joda-time.version>2.3</joda-time.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.coobird</groupId>
            <artifactId>thumbnailator</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0-b01</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jsr303 validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Joda-Time -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>${joda-time.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- To map JodaTime with database type -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
            <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.CR1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet+JSP+JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Apache Commons Upload -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                        <warName>prosvaly</warName>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <finalName>prosvaly</finalName>
    </build>
</project>

@Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    @Import({ SecurityConfig.class })
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = "cz.prosvaly")
    public class AppConfig {

        @Bean
        public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
            InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
            viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
            viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
            viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

            return viewResolver;
        }

        @Bean
        public MessageSource messageSource() {
            ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
            messageSource.setBasename("messages");
            return messageSource;
        }

        @Bean(name="multipartResolver")
        public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver(){
            CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
            multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(10000000);
            return multipartResolver;
        }



    }
```

Dispatcher config:

```
@Configuration
public class DispatcherConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
//        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/css/");
//        registry.addResourceHandler("/html/**").addResourceLocations("/html/");
//        registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("/images/");   
        }
}
```

Spring security

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
      auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).
      usersByUsernameQuery("select username,password, enabled from admin where username=?").
      authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, role from user_roles where username =?  ")
      .passwordEncoder(new Md5PasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

      http.authorizeRequests()
       .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
       .and().formLogin()
       .loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/admin/goods").failureUrl("/login?error")
            .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")        
       .and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
       .and().csrf(); 
    }

}
```

Could someone help me please?

Comment: Are you sure that this is the java file? your error is in the line 39 and the code only has 30 lines.

Comment: Yes, because the class has imports at the begining - that's the reason why I added row with error - now I update my question and added all class with imports

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you post the contents of your Spring security initializer (along with annotations on the class)? I wasn't able to reproduce the error with the given configuration.

Furthermore, looking at your config, a few suggestions:

1. Tomcat 7 doesn't support servlet-api 3.1 and servlet-jsp 2.3. Trying with tomcat 8 might find you some luck.
2. If you decide to stay with tomcat 7, make sure you use the appropriate API versions of the above jars in your pom and mark servlet-api jar as provided as it will be provided by your servlet container ([Specs for Tomcat versions](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html)).
3. Make sure you haven't used changeSessionId in session fixation configuration (if any); it was introduced in servelt-api 3.1.

You would also want to take a look at /etc/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml if there is something wrong with it (in case). Eclipse uses its own configuration metadata for server runtime and copies your server's configuration only while defining a new server.

**UPDATE:**

Also, please annotate your security initializer with `@Order(1)`, remove the `@Configuration` from there as it is provided by `@EnableWebSecurity` and then try. And one more thing, replace the Filter registration line and add the filter directly as `container.addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain", new DelegatingFilterProxy()).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");` Also remove `@Import` line from ur AppConfig.

Comment: Hi I added configuration classes

Comment: Hi, couldn't test your config on how is it working in eclipse but you are trying to register the springSecurityFilterChain twice (in AppInitializer by registering filter and in SecurityInitializer). Please delete the SpringSecurityInitializer class and things should work fine for you. Please post a comment if it doesn't and will test your config :)

Comment: Hi, sorry this class was deleted I post all codes, because I try to combine almost everything to solve this problem :( now springSecurityFilterChain should be initialized only in AppInitializer but, I'm getting the same error on tomcat that runs on Linux server :/

Comment: Hi, sorry for late response was on tight schedule. So, I tried your config and no matter what I to mess it up; it works both in and out of Eclipse and on tomcat 7 and 8. Would suggest you to test your config on a different tomcat instance, may be on a different machine. After all, Java is platform independent! One thing though, can you test if your Linux tomcat instance can connect to the DataSource that you have specified in your SecurityConfig? That may be the only broken piece here resulting in a (silent (logs?)) BeanCreationException for securityChain and hence the null filter.

Comment: Yes I tested it on different machine (so different tomcat instance too). DataSource is ok, because the same datasource is used for hibernate and when I comment out springSecurityFilterChain, i can start appliacation and get data from database (without security)

Comment: Does it work on other machines and instances? Can you please provide full DEBUG logs (the entire stacktrace right from the moment WebApplicationInitializer comes into play till the end)? Also, please annotate your security initializer with `@Order(1)`, remove the @Configuration from there as it is provided by @EnableWebSecurity and then try. And one more thing, replace the Filter registration line and add the filter directly as:

`container.addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain", new DelegatingFilterProxy()).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");` Also remove @Import line from ur AppConfig

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot!!! Now it works like a charm. I will retest all funcionality, but I can deploy and log in, your answer is solution for me

Comment: Hey, then can you please vote it up and accept as the solution so that others can also benefit from the same! :)